# How do you get the Pirate bunny?

Tags: bunni

I can't seem to work out how to get the pirate bunny in [Bunni](http://bunnibunni.com/).

The creator says that I can't have it because I'm not special enough. How can I get special?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you get them by shaking trees. You can read the entire walkthrough in their [wiki](http://bunnibunni.com/walkthrough/index.php/Walkthrough).